# Move Body forward depending the direction is looking

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm making a space shooter horizontal scroll type game with GDX and Box2D. I can´t figured out how a bullet can move forward depending in which direction is looking. For example if the bullet is looking to the right I use applyLinearImpulse, but doesn't work if the bullet is looking upwards, it keeps moving to the right.

Here is the code for the bullet object

```
        BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.bullet = true;
    bd.fixedRotation = true;
    bd.position.set(v);
    bd.type = BodyType.KinematicBody;
    bd.fixedRotation = true;

    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(SIZE);

    FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.shape = circle;
    fd.isSensor = true;

    World world = Game.level.getWorld();

    body = world.createBody(bd);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fd);

    body.setTransform(body.getPosition(), magnitude);
    body.setLinearVelocity(SPEED, 0);

    circle.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bullet is already moving to the right, and you want to make it move up instead, try `SetVelocity`. It will change its velocity directly, as opposed to ApplyImpulse, which tries to make it look realistic.

Comment: The bullet is not moving at the beginning, I want first set the bullet to look to one direction (example top, or top right) and later apply a force for the bullet move forward. So if the bullet is looking upwards, the bullet move to the top, or if the bullet is looking up-right direction, the bullet move forward in that direction

Comment: Well then I don't understand your problem; just pass ApplyLinearImpulse other arguments to make it movein your desired direction. Notice that the first parameter of `ApplyLinearImpule` is relative to the world, not your object's rotation. So if you pass it a vector pointing to the right, it will always move right, regardless of the roation of your body. 

In short: You have to keep track of the rotation yourself and apply the impulse with the proper vector. Does that answer your question?